# Cannot implicitly convert type web service response

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, implicit-conversion

I have a web service which is calling another client web service.

Below is my code which I am using to extract booking details from.

```
ResMsg.GetBookingsOperationRequest request = new ResMsg.GetBookingsOperationRequest();

        int noofBookings = 3;
        DateTime checkInDate;
        DateTime checkOutDate;
        string bookingStatus;
        string Notes;
        int adults;
        int children;
        Int64 bookingID;
        string bookingSource;
        DateTime bookingDate;

        string resResult;
        using (var proxy = new ResMesg.ResonlineMsg.InventoryServiceClient())
        {

            var result = proxy.GetModifiedBookings(request);
            ResMsg.Booking[] bookings= new ResMsg.Booking[noofBookings];
            result.Bookings = new ResMesg.ResonlineMsg.Booking[noofBookings];
            result.Bookings = bookings;

            for (int i = 0; i < bookings.Length; i++)
            {
                Booking bk = new ResMesg.ResonlineMsg.Booking();
                result.Bookings[i]=bk;

                bookingID = bk.BookingId;
                checkInDate = bk.CheckInDate;
                checkOutDate = bk.CheckOutDate;
                adults = bk.Adult;
                children = bk.Children;
                bookingStatus = bk.BookingStatus;
                Notes = bk.Note;
                bookingSource = bk.BookingSource;
                bookingDate = bk.BookingDate;

                bk.GuestInfo = new GuestDetails[noofBookings]; ** Place where error is referring to.GuestDetails is an array. GuestInfo is an instance of GuestDetails.

            }


           return "Success";


    }
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'ResMesg.ResonlineMsg.GuestDetails[]' to
>   'ResMesg.ResonlineMsg.GuestDetails'

**Updated:
Datatype for GuestDetails

```
Field             Data Type      Description
Name              string         Guest's full name. 
Address           string         Guest's address. 
EmailAddress      string         Guest's email address. 
PhoneNumber       string         Guest's phone number.
```

Definition for GuestDetails copied out of the object browser

```
 public GuestDetails GuestInfo { set; get; }
        (Member of Booking)
```

I would be grateful for any sort of advise on how this fix this error or why it is coming. thanks

Comment: GuestInfo is an instance of GuestDetails. and you do "GuestInfo = new GuestDetails[noofBookings]".????

Comment: Sorry am new to this, not sure if I have used the correct context above but am following an example from a previous answer I received sometime ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10096691/1270384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not simply

```
 bk.GuestInfo = new GuestDetails() ;
```

Also lines 19,20,21 look to be doing the same thing.

```
 var details = new GuestDetails[noofBookings] ; 
// fill details array before this..
 bk.GuestInfo = details[noofBookings];
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, from what I can see

`bk.GuestInfo` is a single instance of `GuestDetails`

Whereas you are trying to assign an array to this here

```
bk.GuestInfo = new GuestDetails[noofBookings];
```

So either `bk.GuestInfo` needs to be an Array of `GuestDetails` or you need to change `bk.GuestInfo = new GuestDetails[noofBookings];` to assign a single instance to `bk.GuestInfo`

Comment: Is that wrong? I was following the example to a similar issue I faced some time back : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10096691/1270384

Comment: Show us the code for Booking class(or merely the declaration part of GuestInfo), so that we can see what the declaration looks like.

Comment: No, no, not the definition of GuestDetails, the definition of GuestInfo inside Booking. It should be something like *public GuestDetails GuestInfo;*

Comment: Is the value of GuestInfo suppose to be a single GuestDetails object, or an array. If it is an array, change public GuestDetails GuestInfo { set; get; } to something like public GuestDetails[] GuestInfo { set; get; }

Comment: No no I can't do that its already in the wsdl part of the definitions from the client side that I am connecting to. I need to extract the guest details by calling it in my web service. this is a web service call inside of a web service explained above!

Comment: change bk.GuestInfo = new GuestDetails[noofBookings]; to   bk.GuestInfo = new GuestDetails();

Answer (score 0):

change declaration  of Booking.GuestInfo to array :

```
public GuestDetails[] GuestInfo { set; get; }
```

Comment: Please note comments already mentioned on the top this definition is in the wsdl and beyond my control.if you can just tell me how to extract the info that I need from the service would be great!